# How to tell in .NET whether you are running on x86 or x64?

Tags: .net

Is there a way in .NET (3.5 or less) to tell if a console application is running on x86 or x64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the machine or the process? Why do you want to know?

Aku's answer will tell you if the process you are in is running in a 64bit mode. On current versions of Windows this could mean either Itanuim or x64.

Your process won't necessarily be 64 bit even on a 64 bit machine/OS.

Othewise [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ProcessorArchitecture.CurrentProcessArchitecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.processorarchitecture.currentprocessarchitecture.aspx) returns a string with the current proc arch. It's in 3.5.

Comment: Then there's the OS architecture... (eg. on 32bit Windows running on a 64bit processor)

Answer (score 12):

```
IntPtr.Size == 8 // 64bit
```

If you don't mind to use interop, this function would help: [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx) ([example](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

How about if I have an x64 and an x86 binary dependency on a console application.

Is there a way of deciding at runtime which reference is used dependant on whether we are running on x64 or x86?

Comment: You may want to check out this question/answer for a similar scenario:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108971/using-side-by-side-assemblies-to-load-the-x64-or-x32-version-of-a-dll#156024