# Dynamically loading an assembly based on whether current process is x32 or x64

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have some code which dynamically loads an assembly depending on the result of the Environment.Is64BitProcess property which is then used as required.

Is this something MEF could do automatically without me having to use the Environment & Assembly classes?

Or

Would I have to write some kind of extension to MEF to achieve this?

Framework version: .Net 4.0

Comment: `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` is useless for this.  You can't load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process, even on a 64-bit OS.  (Or by "loading an assembly", did you actually mean "spawning a process"?)

Comment: @BenVoigt I assumed that the OP meant "when it's a 64-bit process I'll load the 64-bit assembly, and when it's 32-bit I'll load the 32-bt assembly".

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah yes, I didn't read it properly.  Yes, the OP should be using `Environment.Is64BitProcess` property.

Comment: @BenVoigt `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` and MEF only exist in .NET 4.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes `IntPtr.Size == 8` to mean "is this process 64-bit" works in all target frameworks, but if you're using a framework version with it built-in, then that's a better choice.  It makes the code more readable.

Comment: sorry, correct should have been Is64BitProcess

Comment: You could just pass a different path to the DirectoryCatalog constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Place 32 bit assemblies in one folder, and 64 bit assemblies in another. Then load the proper folder using MEF based on Environment.Is64BitProcess.