# amd64 and x86 folders

Tags: .net

When I create a website which uses SQL Server Compact/CE 4.0 in private deployment mode then I result in having 2 additional folders inside /bin directory: amd64 and x86 -- which contain the platform specific non-AnyCPU assemblies.

Is this sub folder feature globally available within .NET, is it website specific or even only SQLCE4 specific? And how could I tell? (I already searched System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll using Reflector.)

Comment: @J.Kommer: I'm not really planning to use sql-server-ce at all -- I would like to use a similar technique against SQLite.

Comment: Ah, my bad - in that case I'll undo the tag; [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108971/using-side-by-side-assemblies-to-load-the-x64-or-x32-version-of-a-dll) might be useful to you though!

Comment: I know (and already used) this solution but I'm unable to add a designtime-reference to system.data.sqlite this way. VS2010 (which is x86) always magically finds the amd64 version (even if the project is forced to be x86) and completely ignores the hint path. This results in any WPF window to crash in devenv designer as soon as I just add a reference to System.Data.SQLite.

Comment: It is a feature coded in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: @ErikEJ can you give a hint where to look at inside System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll?

Comment: In NativeMethods.cs - LoadNativeBinariesFromPrivateFolder (used by LoadNativeBinaries, which is called from all over the place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have disassembled using Reflector, and found the relevant code in In NativeMethods.cs - LoadNativeBinariesFromPrivateFolder (used by LoadNativeBinaries, which is called from all over the place).