# Combining C++/CLI, x86, x64 and strong naming

Tags: c#-4.0, c++-cli

Let me get right to the point:

**Main application:**

C# (4.0), AnyCPU.

**Library:**

Wrapper for native .dll written in C++/CLI. Compiled in two versions; x86 and x64, both signed with the same .snk key (using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/11/10140139.aspx) workaround)

**Limitations:**

In the end a single distribution package is required for x86 and x64 platforms.
Main application needs strong name due to references to other strongly named libs.
Rewriting the library using managed C# and P/Invoke is an absolute last way out.

**The problem:**

As long as the main application, at compile time, references the version (x86 or x64) of the library that is needed when run, this is all working fine.

Moving the same compiled output - and exchanging the library with the right platform version during installation - does not work since the signature of the library changes from that of the referenced one.

In a test application without any strong naming I can switch between them as needed.

**The question:**

Is there a way to enable switching between the x86 and x64 libraries within the set limitations, or is strong naming preventing any possible solution other than rewriting the lib?

Let me clarify that it is not a question about finding the correct .dll (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108971/using-side-by-side-assemblies-to-load-the-x64-or-x32-version-of-a-dll/156024#156024)) but about being able to load the .dll once found.

Comment: You say "both signed with .snk key" - but are they signed with the *same* key or with different keys? (Both interpretations are currently possible from your description) If they're signed with the same key, then the strong names *should* be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment got me thinking and he is right in that the strong names are the same, and it was not the actual issue.

I found another difference between the two versions of the library; the output name was set to `nnn.dll` and `nnnx64.dll`. Changing it so that both have the same output name magically made it all work.

Perhaps someone knows why such a setting matters, I certainly don't.