# Cannot load dll file in my project

Tags: c#, dll

In my project i cannot load dll file

dll file --> platform target is x86

and my project --> platform target is Anycpu

machine is running a 64 bit OS

and this is the code i use

```
 pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dllname);
// some code here
static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}
```

why i cannot load this dll file ?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: How do you know you can't load the DLL file?

Comment: You sample is not enough - please instead of `dllname` put static string constant so it is clear that there is no problem with value of the parameter itself, also add excpetion information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that everything else is ok (DLL name etc.):

What you describe is a known problem... for example if your DLL is 32 bit and the OS you are using is 64 Bit then your .NET application will be running in 64 Bit mode...

The easiest solution: IF the DLL is only available in x86 you need to compile for x86 and NOT AnyCPU.

Otherwise you will need a 64 Bit version of that DLL and then you run into a problem known as "side-by-side-assembly"... I think you will find these helpful:

- [Using Side-by-Side assemblies to load the x64 or x32 version of a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108971/using-side-by-side-assemblies-to-load-the-x64-or-x32-version-of-a-dll/156024#156024)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gauravseth/archive/2006/03/07/545104.aspx
- http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/Assembly.aspx